# Sending Triggered email from Email Click

Tags: trigger, ampscript, api, triggered-send

I'm trying to trigger a "Triggered Send" from when a user clicks on a link in an email. At the moment I'm passing users through to a CloudPage, inserting their info into a Triggered Send DE and then trying to send them a triggered email that has the audience of the Triggered Send DE.

I'm getting a 500 error on the cloud page but I can see them being inserted into the DE. I assume my trigger code is incorrect.

Here is my code;

```
%%[
SET @customerId = RequestParameter('customerId')
SET @customerType = RequestParameter('customerType')
SET @Email = RequestParameter('Email')

IF @customerId != '' THEN

InsertDE('Welcome_Journey_Trigger','SubscriberKey', @customerId,'CustomerType', @customerType,'EmailAddress', @Email,)

SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", 5869) 
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)  
SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @Email)
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @Email)

SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)  

   IF @ts_statusCode != 'OK' THEN
       RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
   ENDIF

ENDIF
]%%
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No need to add a row to the trigger DE.  That happens automatically when you trigger an email to a triggered send definition with a DE selected.

Comment: Thanks for your response Adam. I have removed the "InsertDE" line but I still get a 500 error message. Anything else you can see wrong?

Comment: @KaiCurtis your customer key value should be in quotes "5869"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Adam & Noor. Here is the final code that i eventually got working.

```
%%[
    SET @customerId = RequestParameter('customerId')
    SET @customerType = RequestParameter('customerType')
    SET @Email = RequestParameter('Email')

    SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
    SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
    SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "5869") 
    SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)  

    SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
    SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @Email)
    SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @customerId)

    SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "ChannelMemberID")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", "100015131")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)

    SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "CustomerType")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @customerType)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)

    SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)  
       IF @ts_statusCode != 'OK' THEN
          RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
       ENDIF
    ENDIF
]%%
```